# VS 2013 project in VS 2015: Meta data files missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I just installed VS 2015 and tried to continue work on a project i started in VS 2013. Trying to compile it always throws an error: "Meta data file XYZ not found" File: CSC

How to solve this?

I already cleaned and rebuilt the solution and rebuilt each project on it's own. The only one i couldn't build was the "main" project, which has references to the other projects.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps :

1. Clean the Solution.
2. Try Rebuilding the Solution .

Comment: That's what i already did. I also rebuilt each project on it's own. The only one i couldn't build was the "main" project, which has references to the other projects.

Comment: then you should clean and rebuilt the main project as well (be careful to take backup before)

Answer (score 0):

Check that projectdependancies are in correct order. E.g. Project A depends on B. Startup project tries to build A before B. A will throw error that it cannot find dll files of B

Right click on the solution and check Project Dependencies, the Project Build Order should also change according to the dependencies that have been set.

Comment: I deleted the references and added them again. Did not fix the problem.

Comment: @ThomasHahn So, did you fix it? If yes could you share your method with others so they know how to fix it as well?